# Will 0.3 Freya install on an Intel NUC?

Tags: release-freya, system-installation

I have the latest Intel NUC, a 6th gen Skylake model. Does elementary support this hardware?

Answer (score 1):

No, not 0.3.2. The Loki beta does run fine though. You can install 0.3.2, but it probably won't detect your wireless card and you will have video issues, but if you can hardwire in, you can download the hardware enablement stack, then it should work, but even with that, I was still having issues with video performance. I'm sticking with Ubuntu 16.04.1 until Loki stable is released.

Here's how to download the Hardware Enablement kernel in 14.04 (which is what elementary 0.3.2 is based on).

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS - Trusty Tahr

The 14.04.2 and newer point releases will ship with an updated kernel and X stack by default. If you have installed with older media you can use the following to install the newer HWE kernel derived from 16.04 (Xenial):

DESKTOP

sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-core-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-xenial libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-xenial

MULTIARCH DESKTOP

If you run a multiarch desktop (for example, i386 and amd64 on amd64, for gaming or Wine), you may find you need a slightly more involved command, like this:

sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-core-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-xenial libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-xenial libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-xenial libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-xenial:i386 libglapi-mesa-lts-xenial:i386

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

Comment: I noticed Intel makes available Linux drivers here. Any chance of being able to use it? http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking/000005511.html